# Shuffle positions of options in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way of shuffling questions and options in flutter? Like in one question I have 4 options of answer in one card, but only one is correct. When I finish the Quiz and try to play again the order of options does not change its positions like the image.

[image]

So the I'd like the options inside the card change its position, like from first to last or any position. The code below is how I'm trying to make this, getting a list of questions.

```
class Question {
  final int id, answer;
  final String question;
  final List<String> options;

  Question({this.id, this.question, this.answer, this.options});
}

List sample_data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "question":
        "Flutter is an open-source UI software development kit created by ______",
    "options": ['Apple', 'Google', 'Facebook', 'Microsoft'],
    "answer_index": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "question": "When google release Flutter.",
    "options": ['Jun 2017', 'Jun 2017', 'May 2017', 'May 2018'],
    "answer_index": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "question": "A memory location that holds a single letter or number.",
    "options": ['Double', 'Int', 'Char', 'Word'],
    "answer_index": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "question": "What command do you use to output data to the screen?",
    "options": ['Cin', 'Count>>', 'Cout', 'Output>>'],
    "answer_index": 2,
  },
];
```

How the cards are made

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/controllers/question_controller.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/models/Questions.dart';

import '../../../constants.dart';
import 'option.dart';

class QuestionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuestionCard({
    Key key,
    // it means we have to pass this
    @required this.question,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Question question;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionController _controller = Get.put(QuestionController());

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              question.question,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .headline6
                  .copyWith(color: kBlackColor),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: kDefaultPadding),
            ...List.generate(
              question.options.length,
              (index) => Option(
                index: index,
                text: question.options[index],
                press: () => _controller.checkAns(question, index),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The question controler

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/state_manager.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/models/Questions.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/screens/score/score_screen.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/screens/welcome/welcome_screen.dart';

// We use get package for our state management

class QuestionController extends GetxController
    with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {
  // Lets animated our progress bar

  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;
  // so that we can access our animation outside
  Animation get animation => this._animation;

  PageController _pageController;
  PageController get pageController => this._pageController;

  List<Question> _questions = sample_data
      .map(
        (question) => Question(
            id: question['id'],
            question: question['question'],
            options: question['options'],
            answer: question['answer_index']),
      )
      .toList()
        ..shuffle();
  List<Question> get questions => this._questions;

  bool _isAnswered = false;
  bool get isAnswered => this._isAnswered;

  int _correctAns;
  int get correctAns => this._correctAns;

  int _selectedAns;
  int get selectedAns => this._selectedAns;

  // for more about obs please check documentation
  RxInt _questionNumber = 1.obs;
  RxInt get questionNumber => this._questionNumber;

  int _numOfCorrectAns = 0;
  int get numOfCorrectAns => this._numOfCorrectAns;

  // called immediately after the widget is allocated memory
  @override
  void onInit() {
    // Our animation duration is 60 s
    // so our plan is to fill the progress bar within 60s
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 60), vsync: this);
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_animationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        // update like setState
        update();
      });

    // start our animation
    // Once 30s is completed go to the next qn
    _animationController.forward().whenComplete(nextQuestion);
    _pageController = PageController();

    super.onInit();
    if (_questionNumber == _questions.length) {
      reset();
      Get.to(WelcomeScreen());
      _animationController.reset();
    }
  }

  // // called just before the Controller is deleted from memory
  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
    _animationController.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  void checkAns(Question question, int selectedIndex) {
    // because once user press any option then it will run
    _isAnswered = true;
    _correctAns = question.answer;
    _selectedAns = selectedIndex;

    if (_correctAns == _selectedAns) _numOfCorrectAns++;

    // It will stop the counter
    _animationController.stop();
    update();

    // Once user select an ans after 2s it will go to the next qn
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      nextQuestion();
    });
  }

  void nextQuestion() {
    if (_questionNumber.value != _questions.length) {
      _isAnswered = false;
      _pageController.nextPage(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.ease);

      // Reset the counter
      _animationController.reset();

      // Then start it again
      // Once timer is finish go to the next qn
      _animationController.forward().whenComplete(nextQuestion);
    } else {
      // Get package provide us simple way to naviigate another page
      Get.to(ScoreScreen());
    }
  }

  void updateTheQnNum(int index) {
    _questionNumber.value = index + 1;
  }

  void reset() {
    _isAnswered = false;
    _correctAns = 0;
    _selectedAns = 0;
    _questionNumber = 1.obs;
    _numOfCorrectAns = 0;

    //Get.to(WelcomeScreen());
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using `List.shuffle()` is it not working ?

Comment: Maybe you should have this `List<Question> _questions = sample_data.map(......` as a `method` instead of a `property`.

Comment: Yes, it is working for the order of cards only not for the options inside the card.

Comment: I think you should shuffle options separately while mapping map of question into Question model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made it in darpad, so it does not repeat all the widgets from your code, but does shuffle questions and options, and I think uses your model.

Only problem is that we need to change `answer`/`answer_index` too, as the list is shuffled, `answer_index` will not be correct, one very simple way is to do not use index for checking answer just use literal value of an answer(not an index).

Edited that too, which caused small change of your sample data's structure and small formal change of the model of `Question`

```dart
class Question {
  final int id;
  final String question;
  final List<String> options;
  final String answer;

  Question({
    this.id = 0,
    this.question = '',
    this.options = const <String>[],
    this.answer = '',
  });
}

void main() async {
  List sample_data = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question":
          "Flutter is an open-source UI software development kit created by ______",
      "options": ['Apple', 'Google', 'Facebook', 'Microsoft'],
      "answer": 'Apple',
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "When google release Flutter.",
      "options": ['Jun 2017', 'Jun 2017', 'May 2017', 'May 2018'],
      "answer": 'Jun 2017',
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "question": "A memory location that holds a single letter or number.",
      "options": ['Double', 'Int', 'Char', 'Word'],
      "answer": 'Double',
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "question": "What command do you use to output data to the screen?",
      "options": ['Cin', 'Count>>', 'Cout', 'Output>>'],
      "answer": 'Cin',
    },
  ];

  List<Question> questions = sample_data.map((question) {
    // shuffle the options
    List<String> options = question["options"];
    options.shuffle();

    return Question(
        id: question['id'],
        question: question['question'],
        options: options,
        answer: question['answer']);
  }).toList()
    ..shuffle(); // remove this shuffle to check if options are shuffled

  print(questions[0].options);
}
```

Copy and Paste it into [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) and see the result.

Comment: Yeah, it really is shuffling the options, I gonna change on code an give a feedback here.

Comment: Glad to help <3

Comment: It works! As I dont know how to call the method `List<Question> questions = sample_data.map((question) { `  from controler, I putted it on the question controler and I exclude `void main() async {` from where is the list because it says `Error: Getter not found: 'sample_data'.
  List<Question> _questions = sample_data.map((question) {
`